# What is the best iCharger that charges from AA batteries?

Tags: iphone, ipad, battery, charging

I will be leaving on a vacation soon to a place where there are several days between power outlets. What charger should I use to charge/run my iP(ad/hone)?

Comment: Subjective. Should be made community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-built [Mintyboost for iPhone.](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=10&products_id=14) Takes two AA's, and will re-charge your iPhone 4. Will not charge the iPad, but if you go to the project page, they describe the method they used to reverse engineer how much power it takes to charge an iPad.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve had “decent” experience with [this one](http://www.tekkeon.com/products-tekcharge1550.html) with an iPhone 3GS.

I’ve brought that one after reading from someone who actually tested it; you can find his little post: [Here](http://www.marco.org/985141775).

I didn’t test with all those batteries, but I can say that a pack of 4 AA batteries will charge the iPhone from 10-20% to 100%, but the batteries were drained in the process. An expensive idea… but a life saver if you really need it.

> But for long trips away from power
>   sources, non-rechargeable lithium AAs
>   are by far the best

Comment: Note that that will not charge an iPad (there aren't many that do).

Answer (score 1):

After searching the net for a while it seems like current solutions will not charge an iPad with AA batteries. The iPad battery is rated at 25Wh so anything less then that will not even give you 1 full charge. Folowing @Martíns link I found the [Tekkeon myPower ALL Plus MP3450](http://www.tekkeon.com/products-mypall-features.html), rated at 50Wh. It is quite expensive (currently at $160), but it should provide 17 extra hours of use.